# Taskkill through LogMeIn

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd, logmein

I am using a LogMeIn OneToMany task to deploy an update to some PCs running my application. I have a python process that spawns a child .exe. It runs as "python.exe" (what the task list says) and has a title of "Administrator:  AppRunner".

I can't kill python.exe because there are other scripts running that I don't want to die. So, I try to kill based on the title name. The below works locally but does not work when executing through logmein:

```
os.system('taskkill /f /t /fi "WindowTitle eq Administrator:  AppRunner"')
```

I have other taskkills that kill other executables and they work fine e.g.:

```
os.system('taskkill /f /im program.exe')
```

Is there anything obvious that I am missing, or can someone help me with a method to debug something like this so that I can maybe get a hook into the problem?

Comment: I have some further information which explains why the first command is not working... When I run tasklist /v, I get a window title of N/A. I don't understand why that is happening though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have noted yourself, from the Microsoft help pages for  [`taskkill`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725602.aspx):

> The WINDOWTITLE and STATUS filters are not supported when a remote
>   system is specified.

Instead, you could get your child process to write a PIDfile:

```
import os

pid = os.getpid()
with open('c:\\temp\\myapp.pid','w') as pidfile:
    pidfile.write(str(pid))
```

And then when you want to kill the process, get the PID from the file and kill it using `/PID` switch on taskkill. Assuming you've read the PID into a variable `mypid`:

`os.system('taskkill /PID {} /f'.format(mypid))`

Comment: this is basically the approach I ended up with. I killed all python processes except the current one executing. Please add this important note to your answer and I will accept it: The problem ended up being that WindowTitle and Status are not supported operations for filter when performing taskkill on remote machines. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725602.aspx